# How do I remove the recipent's name when sending emails?

Tags: thunderbird

Basically, whenever I send an email, in Thunderbird at least, it includes the recipient’s name that I have saved in my contacts. How do I get rid of that? Example:

What it sends:

```
My Bro<johnny.appleseed@gmail.com>
```

Now if Johnny gets this, he will know his contact name is "My Bro". What I want it to send:

```
<johnny.appleseed@gmail.com>  OR  johnny.appleseed@gmail.com
```

Note no contact name, even though he's in my contacts as "My Bro" and it auto-completes johnny.appleseed@gmail.com from My Bro.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since you're using Thunderbird, *there's an add-on for that.<sup>TM</sup>* ;-) It's called [Auto Address Cleaner](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/thunderbird/addon/auto-address-cleaner/?src=ss). I've been using it for years precisely for this function.

Comment: Is there one for when you send it too? Awesome answer thanks btw.

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand. What Auto Address Cleaner does (quoting from the mozilla add-on download page) is: "Removes comment, display name automatically from addresses before _sending_ mail" (emphasis mine). It works on "To", "Cc", "Bcc" addresses.

Comment: Right, but I sent an email to myself. The To, CC, and BCC are fine, but From still has my name in it. I would also like to clear out the From name as well.

Comment: Oh, well, just clear the field in account settings where you put your name in -- leave it blank. No add-on necessary. In your question you specifically asked about removing recipients` names.